# Run JS Code to fetch data in swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

I needed to fetch the web url of CkAsset in CloudKit. However, in swift, Apple doesn't allow us to fetch the direct WebURL, It only downloads the asset and give us the fileURL. However, with javascript it is possible. Therefore, I wrote an JS file which which fetch the CkAsset WebURL. When I run this javascript file in browser. I'm trying to run it in swift with below code but I can't. As I searched there is a function called "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" but I can't figure out how to run it.

index.html

```
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TIL - Today I Learned</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/ck/1/cloudkit.js" async></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="TIL.js"></script>
```

javascript file:

```
window.addEventListener('cloudkitloaded', function() {
  console.log("listening for cloudkitloaded");
  CloudKit.configure({
    containers: [{
      // To use your own container, replace containerIdentifier and apiToken
      containerIdentifier: 'iCloud.com.emreonder.ogun-dalka-music',
      apiToken: '42ba168168dbf3a8c9562904ebf311864258f8dd3638a241d2372057ea0e8a55',
      environment: 'development'
    }]
  });
  console.log("cloudkitloaded");

    var self = this;
    console.log("get default container");
    var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();

    console.log("set publicDB");
    var publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();

    // Fetch public records
  //  self.fetchRecords = function() {
      console.log("fetching records from " + publicDB);
      var query = { recordType: 'Musics'};

      // Execute the query.
      return publicDB.performQuery(query).then(function(response) {
        if(response.hasErrors) {
          console.error(response.errors[0]);
          return;
        }
        var records = response.records;
        var numberOfRecords = records.length;
        if (numberOfRecords === 0) {
          console.error('No matching items');
          return;
        }

        console.log(records.length + " records")
        console.log(records);
        self.items(records);
      });
  //  };
});
```

Swift File:

```
 let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")
    let myRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(myRequest as URLRequest);
    print(webView.pageCount)
    let test_string = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "function();")
    print(test_string)
```

EDIT: I put html file also but now i don't know how to call the javascript function.

Comment: evaluate js method is a public method of a WK/UIWebview, you need to load first it into webview they run your js

Comment: It says "has no initializers". Do i need to implement delegate or something?

Answer (score 0):

Okey after hard tries. I figured to solve my problem. Via this solution, u can fetch the stream url on CloudKit (For example assets).

First I created a webView (Actually, it is just in code, there is nothing in GUI).

```
  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")
    let myRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(myRequest as URLRequest);
    webView.delegate = self
```

Then I fetch the variable in my js file via stringByEvaluatingJavaScript function (I needed to create a variable below the function in js file

```
 let a = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "myVar")
    print(a!)
    let url : NSString = a! as NSString
    let urlStr : NSString = url.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSString
    let searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr as String)!
    print(searchURL)
    /*https://cvws.icloud-content.com/B/AVHgxc_-X3u9H5xK684KmUQrzDqp/$%7Bf%7D?o=Apgif1Giyg-lwRiNre2KJYl-5EhUAiL1m1OgE3-osxpxexWD7YGjCAOFCoQLRv8sGUglywu2tGr-OgfGtDZ15k0&v=1&x=3&a=BbLB0UptOX3bA-k6OQ&e=1487341935&k=_&fl=&r=0f83571c-d168-4743-b38b-0e808baa0a1a-1&ckc=iCloud.com.emreonder.ogun-dalka-music&ckz=_defaultZone&p=61&s=OuE127GKlo_0EIZ6y5t49gMv0qM 
     */
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: searchURL as URL)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    self.player.play()
```